# Insert directory full of svg files into html as one element

Tags: html, svg, figma

I had to reproduce this button as an svg :

[image]

I used Figma and since the background is a gradient, the svg background had to be transparent.
I know how to insert a single svg but here I have a directory full of tiny svg dashes and I have no idea how it's supposed to be inserted.
Could anyone help ?

Thank you !

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What does the background of your example have to do with how to insert multiple SVG files?